# What is the use of ParameterDirection?

Tags: c#, parameters

I am new to C#. In some code, I saw a attribute called ParameterDirection. Can anyone tell me what is it? And how it is used?

Comment: provide some code and context

Comment: Not specific to code. I want some general information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParameterDirection` is used the get the value of `OUTPUT` parameter, `ReturnValue` from `Stored procedure` in `.NET`.

Refer the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class ExecuteAddProduct {
    public static void Main() {
        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=Northwind;uid=sa;pwd=sa");
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText =
          "EXECUTE AddProduct @MyProductID OUTPUT, @MyProductName, " +
          "@MySupplierID, @MyCategoryID, @MyQuantityPerUnit, " +
          "@MyUnitPrice, @MyUnitsInStock, @MyUnitsOnOrder, " +
          "@MyReorderLevel, @MyDiscontinued";

        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyProductID", SqlDbType.Int);
        mySqlCommand.Parameters["@MyProductID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = "Widget";
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MySupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyCategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyQuantityPerUnit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = "1 per box";
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyUnitPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = 5.99;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyUnitsInStock", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = 10;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyUnitsOnOrder", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = 5;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyReorderLevel", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = 5;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyDiscontinued", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("New ProductID = " + mySqlCommand.Parameters["@MyProductID"].Value);
        mySqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 type of ParameterDirection Input,Output,InputOutput,ReturnValue.
ParameterDirection is used from the namespace Using System.Data

It can be used to assign dbull as below

```
foreach (SqlParameter param in commandParameters)
{
    if( param != null )
    {
        //It will check for input and output parameter
        if ( ( param.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput || 
            param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input ) && 
            (param.Value == null))
        {
            param.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        command.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}
```